# Apollo data object is empty after sumbit a mutation

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo

I am currently using apollo to make a transfer (adding a user) on my project and when the response my object data is empty. Do you know why ?

this is my schema type

```
  type UserKyrios {
    _id: ObjectId!
    firstname: String!
    lastname: String!
    email: String!
    password: String!
    creationDate: Date
  }
`;
```

and this is my input type

```
  input UserKyriosInput {
    firstname: String!
    lastname: String!
    email: String!
    password: String!
  }
`;
```

Definition type Mutation

```
  type Mutation {
    upsertUserKyrios(user: UserKyriosInput!): UserKyrios
  }
```

My querie mutation

```
mutation UpsertUserKyrios($user: UserKyriosInput!) {
    upsertUserKyrios(user: $user) {
        ...userKyriosFields
        creationDate
    }
  }
```

My output

```
data: {upsertUserKyrios: null}
upsertUserKyrios: null
```

My resolver

```
upsertUserKyrios: async (_, __, { server }) => server.plugins.mongodb.UserKyrios.insertOne(),
```

My script component

```
<script>
import { UPSERT_USER_KYRIOS } from '../../../../graphql/KyriosMutations';

export default {
  name: 'addUserModalComponent',
  props: {
    dialog: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  data: () => ({
    user: {
      firstname: '',
      lastname: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
    },
  }),
  methods: {
    closeDialog() {
      this.$emit('closeModal');
    },
    async submitForm() {
      const userCreated = await this.$apollo.mutate({
        mutation: UPSERT_USER_KYRIOS,
        variables: {
          user: this.user,
        },
      });
      console.log(userCreated);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvers gives you some information about the reqoust:

1st param: Parent

2nd param: args => contains the request payload

3d param: context

4th param: info

Mutation data exist in the second param that you dont use (args).
args will contain an object. In your case `user` with the values from the client request. ($variables).

```
upsertUserKyrios: async (_, args, { server }) =>
```

#### In the client side:

when you submit the form send all the necessary info in the veriables object (UserKyriosInput)

```
variables: {
  user: {
    firstname: this.user.firstName
    lastname: this.user.lastName
    email: this.user.email
    password: this.user.password
  }
}
```

or

```
variables: {
  user: {
    ...this.user
  }
}
```

Hope make sence.

Answer (score 0):

Your resolver seems to be missing info. Your second argument in the resolver doesn’t seem to be handling any incoming data from the fields. Also, once those arguments come in, maybe I don’t know enough about Mongo, but shouldn’t you be sending the data to be inserted as an object in the insertOne function?

We also should see what your gql definition looks like.

Comment: I added user variable like this but it doesn't work 

upsertUserKyrios: async (_, { user }, { server }) => server.plugins.mongodb.UserKyrios.insertOne(user),

Comment: You're definitely going to have to pass some sort of data as the second argument. It should come like you have there. It wouldn't be a bad idea to console.log(user) in your resolver to verify the data is getting there. If it's not, you potentially defined the mutation incorrectly. If you could also update your original post to include what `import { UPSERT_USER_KYRIOS } from '../../../../graphql/KyriosMutations';` actually imports would be great.

Comment: I think that the problem is my mutation declaration because when I remove resolvers I've got the same things ...

Comment: That’s what it sounds like we’re getting at. In your question there isn’t quite enough info to determine where to go. Need to debug a bit more on where the data is flowing.

Answer (score 0):

When an error happens, the data returns empty. You need to look for the complete response. And error is probably present there.

Not sure where is the this.$apollo.mutate comming from, but the mutate usually returns a promise.

One good way to use them is with hooks: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations/